# python diagram: change x axis inside out

Tags: python

Is there an easy way to change the diagram in Python in order to put the outside-values of the x-axis to the inside? To visualize it with an array it would be like that: [1,2,3,4,5] -> change to -> [4,5,1,2,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the numpy.roll function to achieve something like this:

```
x_new = numpy.array(x)
y_new = numpy.array(y)

x_new = numpy.roll(x_new, len(x_new)/2)
y_new = numpy.roll(y_new, len(y_new)/2)
```

Now x_new and y_new are in the order that you want.